# Как в CSS задать цвет для GRID-линии?

Tags: html, css, grid

Как сделать так, чтобы в блоке с display: grid были выделены грид-линии (серым цветом например)?
Мне нужно узнать это чтобы сверстать адаптивную таблицу.

Comment: Задать цвет для линии нельзя, но можно задать цвет фону и окрасить блоки в непрозрачный цвет, создастся иллюзия того, что линии окрашены, а на самом деле окрашен фон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока `grid-gap` перекрасить нельзя, но есть решение на html и css [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792755/show-border-grid-lines-only-between-elements/47914693#47914693)

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.item {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```